# Does SOAP api for google Calendar exist?

Tags: web-services, soap, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I am trying to access google calendar from a cloud based application to create / delete / update events on google calendar. The front end will be developed later on.

Unfortunately, I can use webservices with SOAP apis only currently (only this is supported).

I wanted to know if a SOAP api for google Calendar exists? i searched google which did not give me good answers on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SOAP API but there is a REST API:
http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html

If you could explain your limitation we can possibly discuss workarounds.